# R regex to extract information from string

Tags: python, regex, r

Someone tell me R is a good tool for data processing. so I am trying to figure out if it's possible (easy) to do regex data extraction with R.

Below is a example from Python to extract two key information:

```
import re

str = "oh, 100.0 dollar is 621.5 yuan"
m = re.search("([\d+\.\d+]+).*?([\d+\.\d+]+)",str)
if m:
    print m.group(1),"->",m.group(2)
```

Output of Python is:

```
100.0 -> 621.5
```

Really cool result from Python, but how to do it efficiently in R?

Comment: Python has many tools for data processing as well. You don't need to learn R just to do that.

Comment: R supports regex as well, have you tried anything yet? http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, your regular expression is incorrect and does match what you expect. A [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) defines a set of characters. Saying — "match **one** character specified by the class".

Therefore, it matches the following:

```
[\d+\.\d+]+   # any character of: digits (0-9), '+', '\.', digits (0-9), '+' 
              # (1 or more times)
```

Using base R you could use `regmatches` and `gregexpr` with the below pattern:

```
x <- 'oh, 100.0 dollar is 621.5 yuan'
m <- regmatches(x, gregexpr('\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?', x, perl=T))[[1]]
paste(m[1], '->', m[2])
# [1] "100.0 -> 621.5"
```

Regular Expression ( *Explained* )

```
\d+           # digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
(?:           # group, but do not capture (optional):
  \.          #   '.'
  \d+         #   digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
)?            # end of grouping
```

Comment: Great, but if not match,what's m[1] and m[2]?

Comment: why don't you try it and see?

Answer (score 6):

Sure. Something like this is also easily possible either with base R or with one of its many packages. Here's an example with the "stringi" package.

```
library(stringi)
m <- stri_extract_all_regex(str, "\\d+\\.\\d")[[1]]
sprintf("%s -> %s", m[1], m[2])
# [1] "100.0 -> 621.5"
```

---

A base R equivalent of the above might be to use `gregexpr` and `regmatches`:

```
regmatches(str, gregexpr("\\d+\\.\\d+", str))[[1]]
# [1] "100.0" "621.5"
```

Comment: I was going to go with `stri_match_all`, but this is just as good :)

Comment: This example two pattern is the same, how about if it's different pattern? such as first one match digital but second one match a string?

Comment: @Beatlej, then you would need to supply a more specific regex, perhaps using the `|` in your pattern to specify the options.

Comment: @Beatlej you would need to use alternation. i.e. `\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?| ( ... )`

Answer (score 3):

Here are some approaches.  Others are possible too with a variety of other packages.

**1)** It can be done in one line with `strapply` (although we will break it into two for readability). `strapply` applies the pattern `pat` to the string `str` and then inputs the captured strings to the function (expressed here in formula notation) and returns the result:

```
library(gsubfn)

# test data
str <- "oh, 100.0 dollar is 621.5 yuan"

pat <- "([\\d+\\.\\d+]+).*?([\\d+\\.\\d+]+)"   
strapply(str, pat, ~ paste(x, "->", y), simplify = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
[1] "100.0 -> 621.5"
```

**Note** that we used the same regex as in the question to show that the python regex works in R too (although we need to double the backslashes when writing it out since "\\" represents one backslash); however, we could simplify the regex slightly by using this instead:

```
pat <- "(\\d+\\.\\d+).*?(\\d+\\.\\d+)"
```

or possibly this would be sufficient:

```
pat <- "([\\d.]+).*?([\\d.]+)"
```

In the subsequent points we use even simpler regular expressions.

**2)**  We could also simplify the pattern like this in which case this works using `strapplyc` from the same package.

```
s <- strapplyc(str, "\\d+\\.\\d+")[[1]]
paste(s[1], "->", s[2])
```

giving the same answer.

**3)** A different approach is to split the input into words then keep only the words that represent numbers.  This one does not use any packages:

```
g <- grep("\\d+\\.\\d+", strsplit(str, " ")[[1]], value = TRUE)
paste(g[1], "->", g[2])
```

giving the same answer.

Comment: The question is not clear but all the answers give the same result on `str`.

Comment: Well, that is the regex that the poster used so I used the same regex to show that the python regex works in R too (modulo doubling the backslashes) since I think that was the point of the question.  I will add a note on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the one through series of  `gsub` functions.

```
> str = "oh, 100.0 dollar is 621.5 yuan"
> sub("[[:space:]]+", " -> ", gsub("^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$", "", gsub("(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)|\\S", '\\1', str, perl=T)))
[1] "100.0 -> 621.5"
```

Try this if the input contains more than two numbers. I just replaced the `sub` function in the above with `gsub`

```
> str = "oh, 100.0 dollar is 621.5 yuan 700 to 888.78"
> gsub("[[:space:]]+", " -> ", gsub("^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$", "", gsub("(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)|\\S", '\\1', str, perl=T)))
[1] "100.0 -> 621.5 -> 700 -> 888.78"
```

`[[:space:]]+` POSIX character class which matches one or more spaces.